# Calculate arrival time on iOS based on target distance

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, titanium, distance

First off I'm using Appcelerators Titanium Platform, so any Javascript examples would be appreciated. I'll give the overall goal of what I'm trying to accomplish. My app will allow a user to input the following:

- Goal Time (17:00 minutes)
- Run Distance (2.0 miles)

As a person is running, I need to alert them of their current estimated finish time. I'm already successfully gathering distance from the gps on the app. And I have a stopwatch running as well. So really I just would like to get some insight as to how I would calculate their estimated finish time based on their distance and time at any given point. This probably requires some simple math calculations that are escaping me at this point, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
So in the end, I have the following pieces of information:

Set by user

- Goal Time (17:00 minutes)
- Run Distance (2.0 miles)

From phone

- Distance
- Timer Time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way. This is just an algorithm I m not sure about the syntax (hope you can fix it).

```
function calculateEstimateFinishTime(userDistance,takenTime,goalDistance)
{
 /*
   userDistance is distance from phone in miles
   takenTime is Timer Time in minutes
   goalDistance is user input Run Distance in miles
   the function return estimatedFinishTime in minutes
 */
  var speed = userDistance/takenTime;
  return (goalDistance/speed);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the time in looking into my question. Your formula may be correct and i'm just not implementing correctly, but the "Finish Time" just keeps increasing and never matches what the actual finish time is. The values are as follows

[INFO] 1.02 userDistance in miles
[INFO] 0.93 userTime in minutes
[INFO] 2.0 goalDistance in miles
[INFO] 2.19 finishValue

Perhaps its how i am using the time or distance values?
Maybe the time should be in seconds instead?

Comment: @Chris I have made a small modification in answer.

Comment: I believe that did it! Thanks for all your help!